# Unity built apps crashes for android 32+ builds with unity 2022...+ versions?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

- Building android app out of basic and default 3d scene. * With no codes or any edits. Just to test if it works for android. * Tested with multiple Unity versions and emulator versions.
- All tools and requirements are downloaded and install completed both with Unity Hub and Android Studio.
- After build is completed, installed on android 33 emulator with google play services, it crashes on or after the splash screen.
- Android studio shows a lot of errors on logcat and run window, I can not figure out their meaning or reasons or solution.

some of errors:

```
   A/pany.Myproject4: runtime.cc:675]   (no managed stack frames)
    runtime.cc:675] 
    runtime.cc:675] "FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" prio=5 tid=15 Waiting
    runtime.cc:675]   | group="" sCount=1 ucsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12c35038 self=0x78b036508ad0
    runtime.cc:675]   | sysTid=8040 nice=4 cgrp=top-app sched=0/0 handle=0x78ae5afa4cf0
    runtime.cc:675]   | state=S schedstat=( 218112 4742853 2 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
    runtime.cc:675]   | stack=0x78ae5aea2000-0x78ae5aea4000 stackSize=1035KB
    runtime.cc:675]   | held mutexes=
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #00 pc 000000000005bd56  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (syscall+22) (BuildId: 57def992cb1772e13608c8efcafd893b)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #01 pc 00000000003f96ee  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+110) (BuildId: 010f73d48be32cf8a77d6c31ff28077e)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #02 pc 00000000007196a9  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Monitor::Wait(art::Thread*, long, int, bool, art::ThreadState)+601) (BuildId: 010f73d48be32cf8a77d6c31ff28077e)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #03 pc 000000000071af3c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Monitor::Wait(art::Thread*, art::ObjPtr<art::mirror::Object>, long, int, bool, art::ThreadState)+316) (BuildId: 010f73d48be32cf8a77d6c31ff28077e)
    runtime.cc:675]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native method)
    runtime.cc:675]   - waiting on <0x0c056076> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
    runtime.cc:675]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:442)
    runtime.cc:675]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:568)
    runtime.cc:675]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepUntilNeeded(Daemons.java:385)
    runtime.cc:675]   - locked <0x0c056076> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
    runtime.cc:675]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:365)
    runtime.cc:675]   at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:140)
    runtime.cc:675]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
    runtime.cc:675] 
    runtime.cc:675] "binder:8004_3" prio=5 tid=16 Native
    runtime.cc:675]   | group="" sCount=1 ucsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12e00020 self=0x78b03650a6a0
    runtime.cc:675]   | sysTid=8049 nice=0 cgrp=top-app sched=0/0 handle=0x78ae5aae1cf0
    runtime.cc:675]   | state=S schedstat=( 78868 208711 2 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2 HZ=100
    runtime.cc:675]   | stack=0x78ae5a9eb000-0x78ae5a9ed000 stackSize=987KB
    runtime.cc:675]   | held mutexes=
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #00 pc 00000000000b78c7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__ioctl+7) (BuildId: 57def992cb1772e13608c8efcafd893b)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #01 pc 00000000000691e8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (ioctl+216) (BuildId: 57def992cb1772e13608c8efcafd893b)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #02 pc 0000000000084737  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+295) (BuildId: b3a72b1c424e4f5102278f425945a7c8)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #03 pc 0000000000084607  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::PoolThread::threadLoop()+23) (BuildId: b3a72b1c424e4f5102278f425945a7c8)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #04 pc 000000000001377f  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+175) (BuildId: bf3f66fd6f5b7c78306a1c8270331f22)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #05 pc 00000000000e1bec  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+140) (BuildId: b950a9a75dc46caf12ef19f599b16141)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #06 pc 00000000000cccba  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+58) (BuildId: 57def992cb1772e13608c8efcafd893b)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #07 pc 0000000000060cc7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+55) (BuildId: 57def992cb1772e13608c8efcafd893b)
    runtime.cc:675]   (no managed stack frames)
    runtime.cc:675] 
    runtime.cc:675] "binder:8004_4" prio=5 tid=17 Native
    runtime.cc:675]   | group="" sCount=1 ucsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12e40020 self=0x78b0365115e0
    runtime.cc:675]   | sysTid=8051 nice=0 cgrp=top-app sched=0/0 handle=0x78ae5a9e4cf0
A/pany.Myproject4: runtime.cc:675]   | state=S schedstat=( 544912 468940 2 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
    runtime.cc:675]   | stack=0x78ae5a8ee000-0x78ae5a8f0000 stackSize=987KB
    runtime.cc:675]   | held mutexes=
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #00 pc 00000000000b78c7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__ioctl+7) (BuildId: 57def992cb1772e13608c8efcafd893b)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #01 pc 00000000000691e8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (ioctl+216) (BuildId: 57def992cb1772e13608c8efcafd893b)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #02 pc 0000000000084737  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+295) (BuildId: b3a72b1c424e4f5102278f425945a7c8)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #03 pc 0000000000084607  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::PoolThread::threadLoop()+23) (BuildId: b3a72b1c424e4f5102278f425945a7c8)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #04 pc 000000000001377f  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+175) (BuildId: bf3f66fd6f5b7c78306a1c8270331f22)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #05 pc 00000000000e1bec  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+140) (BuildId: b950a9a75dc46caf12ef19f599b16141)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #06 pc 00000000000cccba  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+58) (BuildId: 57def992cb1772e13608c8efcafd893b)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #07 pc 0000000000060cc7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+55) (BuildId: 57def992cb1772e13608c8efcafd893b)
    runtime.cc:675]   (no managed stack frames)
    runtime.cc:675] 
    runtime.cc:675] "Profile Saver" prio=5 tid=18 Native
    runtime.cc:675]   | group="" sCount=1 ucsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12ec0020 self=0x78b03650fa10
    runtime.cc:675]   | sysTid=8052 nice=9 cgrp=top-app sched=0/0 handle=0x78ae5a8e7cf0
    runtime.cc:675]   | state=S schedstat=( 181923 1036807 1 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
    runtime.cc:675]   | stack=0x78ae5a7f1000-0x78ae5a7f3000 stackSize=987KB
    runtime.cc:675]   | held mutexes=
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #00 pc 000000000005bd58  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (syscall+24) (BuildId: 57def992cb1772e13608c8efcafd893b)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #01 pc 00000000003f9ae4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::TimedWait(art::Thread*, long, int)+148) (BuildId: 010f73d48be32cf8a77d6c31ff28077e)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #02 pc 00000000005c5385  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ProfileSaver::Run()+229) (BuildId: 010f73d48be32cf8a77d6c31ff28077e)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #03 pc 00000000005cb7eb  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ProfileSaver::RunProfileSaverThread(void*)+171) (BuildId: 010f73d48be32cf8a77d6c31ff28077e)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #04 pc 00000000000cccba  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+58) (BuildId: 57def992cb1772e13608c8efcafd893b)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #05 pc 0000000000060cc7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+55) (BuildId: 57def992cb1772e13608c8efcafd893b)
    runtime.cc:675]   (no managed stack frames)
    runtime.cc:675] 
    runtime.cc:675] Aborting thread:
    runtime.cc:675] "Thread-3" prio=10 tid=19 Native
    runtime.cc:675]   | group="" sCount=0 ucsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x12f40000 self=0x78b0365131b0
    runtime.cc:675]   | sysTid=8071 nice=-10 cgrp=top-app sched=0/0 handle=0x78ae51bb7cf0
    runtime.cc:675]   | state=R schedstat=( 30360789 7013611 44 ) utm=1 stm=1 core=1 HZ=100
    runtime.cc:675]   | stack=0x78ae51ac1000-0x78ae51ac3000 stackSize=987KB
    runtime.cc:675]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #00 pc 000000000071e4c4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*, bool)+132) (BuildId: 010f73d48be32cf8a77d6c31ff28077e)
A/pany.Myproject4: runtime.cc:675]   native: #01 pc 000000000084245e  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+334) (BuildId: 010f73d48be32cf8a77d6c31ff28077e)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #02 pc 0000000000804fe9  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::AbortState::DumpThread(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, art::Thread*) const+57) (BuildId: 010f73d48be32cf8a77d6c31ff28077e)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #03 pc 0000000000804c75  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::AbortState::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+421) (BuildId: 010f73d48be32cf8a77d6c31ff28077e)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #04 pc 00000000007ecf35  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+1381) (BuildId: 010f73d48be32cf8a77d6c31ff28077e)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #05 pc 0000000000019cfc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+60) (BuildId: 9335a3052c0ad43b3680057cf90b0afe)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #06 pc 0000000000008712  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+338) (BuildId: 6b5490b5683793c72167e11556e0b7d9)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #07 pc 00000000001f90d5  /system/lib64/libndk_translation.so (ndk_translation::intrinsics::Arm64WriteToFpcr(unsigned long)+213) (BuildId: ff7f956887230c9b0a41d98c9117a6d1)
    runtime.cc:675]   native: #08 pc 000000000033f8e5  <anonymous:78ae52cb5000> (???)
    runtime.cc:675]   (no managed stack frames)
    runtime.cc:675] 
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 8071 (Thread-3), pid 8004 (pany.Myproject4)
```